# Provide incbin path as a predefined macro in both NASM and GCC

Tags: gcc, assembly, nasm, gnu-assembler

I want to embed a binary file in an executable, in a way that is portable to both Windows and Linux.

For achieving this, I want to use an assembly file with the directive `incbin`. For example:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix


      .global _img0_start
      .global _img0_end
      .global _img0_size


_img0_start:   .incbin "img0.bin"
_img0_end:
_img0_size:    .quad  $ -  _img0_start
```

I can't know where the binary files will be before compiling the above assembly file, so I want to **replace `img0.bin` by a macro**, and define it within the command line arguments as if I were using the `gcc` option `-D` for defining a macro constant.

I have seen that there exists the `-d Option: Pre-Define a Macro`, that allows to do exactly the above but only for numeric values (I need to provide a path to a file). (font: https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.19)

**Is there anything like `-d`, but that allows to define strings, and works for moth `gas` and `nasm`?**

Comment: Would probably be easier to have your build system copy/link the file to the expected name. Alternatively you could use preprocessed assembly. `gcc` knows to invoke the preprocessor on `.S` files or you can use a command line switch. You'd have to run the preprocessor on the nasm file yourself.

Comment: I think NASM `-DFOO=bar` works for arbitrary text substitutions.  You can certainly use NASM `%define` macros inside your file for non-integers; only `equ` constants have to be numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have read more and I have realized that there is no need for a macro that expands to a string.

Instead, what can be done is just providing a fixed name for the binary file, in my case, `img0.bin`, and then use the `-I` option for providing extra paths for searching such file.

In other words, with the same assembly file as above (let it be `assembly_file.s`), just do:

`gcc -c assembly_file.s -I<path_to_folder_that_contains_img0.bin> -o <output_file_name>`

Answer (score 1):

NASM macros and the C preprocessor both allow arbitrary strings.

NASM `equ` constants have to be integers, but `%define foo eax` or `nasm '-DIMG="foo.bin"'` both work.

**Notice that the macro definition *includes* the double quotes.**  CPP makes it easy to expand a macro inside double quotes, but I didn't bother to check if NASM can easily do that.

It's normally easy to create a double-quoted string like that in Make or whatever.

---

```
;;; foo-nasm.asm  NASM source
incbin IMG
```

```
# foo-gas.S   GAS source (capital S gets GCC to run it through CPP)
.incbin IMG
```

`hi.bin` contains `B8 68 69 00 00`, the 32/64-bit machine code for  `mov eax, 'hi'`

---

```
 $ gcc -c foo-gas.S -DIMG='"hi.bin"'            
 $ nasm -felf64 foo-nasm.asm -DIMG='"hi.bin"'       

$ disas foo-gas.o
...
0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   b8 68 69 00 00          mov    eax,0x6968

$ disas foo-nasm.o
...
0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   b8 68 69 00 00          mov    eax,0x6968
```